# graphql apollo-datasource-rest pass jwt tokens from frontend to authenticate custom REST APIs

Tags: node.js, graphql, datasource, apollo-server

How to pass in JWT token from frontend to Apollo graphql server and forward that to call custom datasource REST APIs on different server to pull each logged in user's profile info?

Answer (score 0):

solved it, didn't know it was quite simple.

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
        schema,
        dataSources,
        context: ({ req }) => {
            let authToken = null;
            try {
                authToken = req.headers[AUTH_TOKEN];

                if (!authToken) {
                     console.error(`No ${AAUTH_TOKENU} header present.`)
                }
             } catch (e) {
                console.warn(`Unable to authenticate using auth token: ${authToken}`);
             }
             console.log(authToken)
             return {
                 db, authToken
             }
        } 
    });
```

You can pass the token in the resolvers definitions.